# Cannot erase HD partition - Could not find partition to expand, first partition on the disk?

Tags: time-machine, disk-utility

My current HD status is
[image]

When I try to remove the "Free" partition, the log returns
"Could not find partition to expand, first partition on the disk?"

What can I do?

Comment: No, I'm admin.
Erase and RAID & Restore is showed only when you select a partition, in the image is selected the disk.

Comment: I get First Aid, Erase, Partition, RAID, Restore - if I select just a Volume, then just Partition disappears. I also have far more technical info in the bottom section. I don't know whether it's truly relevant, but it looks like you're not seeing half the potential info.

Comment: What do you mean by REMOVE the partition.?

Comment: @Tetsujin it's formatted as a LVG because it's encrypted. That's why those tabs are missing.

Comment: Can you please update your post with the output of the following command entered in Terminal: `diskutil list; echo; diskutil cs list`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to proceed as follows:

1. Stop Time Machine,
2. Migrate your backups from: `Time Machine - …` to `Free`. If required,
   refer to this Apple technical note: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5096
3. Suppress your now useless `Tine Machine - …` partition.

   ⇒ `Free` should now use your full disk
4. Rename your `Free` partition to something more practical.
5. Restart Time Machine and tell it to make the backup where you want.